# What GUI API does limewire use?

Tags: java, user-interface

I've only seen limewire though screenshots, and i feel atracted to its GUI's look.
What "API" does it use? It's clearly NOT swing, awt, or any other common API.

BTW: that IS called an API, right? Or would it be library?

Comment: Toolkit is a common word for GUI libraries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Java swing as far as I remember.

**EDIT**

Yes, it is Java, and guess what? limewire is open source. You can [check it here!](http://www.limewire.com/development) and see it for your self.

Comment: Might be with a custom LAF freely available such as:

http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/looksdemo/index.html

(check the webstart demo)

Comment: Oh, didn't notice it was Open Source. Doesn't look like swing, but I'll take a look, thanks.